# What's the easiest way to convert a number to a percentage in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm calculating the difference in size of images after they've been resized by the user. I take the images new width and divide it by the natural width. This is the code:

`Math.round( (img.width / naturalWidth) * 100) / 100`

The numbers I get as a result can look like the following (and the numbers commented out are what I'd like to convert them to).

```
0       // 0%
1       // 100%
1.2     // 120%
1.39402 // 139%
1.39502 // 140%
21.56   // 216%
0.4     // 40%
0.44    // 44%
0.1     // 10%
0.01    // 1%
0.005   // 1%
0.0049  // 0%
```

Never negative numbers. I need to round these numbers and then convert them into strings represented as percentages. Is there an easy and straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: See my answer. It works perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Math.round` like this:

```
 Math.round((img.width/ naturalWidth) * 100));
```

---

A simple example:

```js
    var a = 1.2;
    var b = 1;
    
    alert(Math.round((a / b) * 100) + '%');  // 120%
```

Comment: Use `round` note the example `1.39402 // 140%`

Comment: `Math.floor` will return an absolute integer, there's no reason to `round` it. You should use one or another.

Comment: For some clarity, I suppose I actually meant for `1.39402` to be `1.39502`. The former should definitely be 139% while the latter should round to 140%.

Comment: All of that said, I believe @GeorgeMauer was right about using `round` instead of `Math.floor`. My initial typo means your answer is not what I'm actually looking for. You answered first so I'll accept yours if you edit it!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
const formatAsPercentage = x => `${Math.round(x * 100)}%`
```

You can use it as:

```
formatAsPercentage(.05) // => "5%"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used in own project

```js
function calculatePercent(config){
    var currentProgressPercent;
    var totalRecords = Number.parseFloat(config.totalRecords);
    var current = Number.parseFloat(config.current);
    currentProgressPercent = 0;
    if (!(isNaN(totalRecords) || isNaN(current))) {
        currentProgressPercent = (totalRecords === 0 ? 100 : Math.round((current / totalRecords) * 100));
    }

    currentProgressPercent += '%';
    return currentProgressPercent;
}

var input = [0, 1, 1.2, 2.156, 0.4, 0.44, 0.1, 0.01, 0.005, 0.0049];
input.forEach(function(value){
     alert(calculatePercent({current:value, totalRecords: 1}));
});
```

You might do some refactoring for your needs in variable names.

Answer (score 1):

First multiply the number by 100 then use `Math.round()` to round the result. Finally, add the percent sign:

```
Math.round(img.width / naturalWidth * 100) + "%";
```